# Is it clean for an object to generate another object when not in a factory design?

Tags: oop, coupling

Say you a class ZipFile and a class Content.
ZipFile has a load() method for reading the contents of all files in the zip archive and put it in a Content object.
What is the most appropriate OOP design ?

**1) ZipFile.load() will create a Content object**

```
class ZipFile
{
    public function load()
    {
        // Load all files in zip
        // ...
        Content content = new Content();
        content->set(data);
        return( content );
    }
}
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile();
Content ct = zf->load();
ct->print();
```

**B) Give the ZipFile constructor a Content object to fill**

```
class ZipFile
{
    private Content content;

    public function ZipFile(content) // constructor
    {
        this->content = content;
    }    
    public function load()
    {
        // Load all files in zip 
        // ...
        this->content->set(data);
    }
}
Content ct = new Content();
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(ct);
zf->load();
ct->print();
```

Basically, is it better to separate objects (loose coupling) ?
As an old-school procedural programmer I cannot stop questionning the several ways of designing OOP. I lose a lot of time on "what is the best way to *OOP this*. Any advice to think it through ? Book ? Website ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: why don't you give the `Content` object to the `load` function  instead of the constructor? that would be more equivalent to the first example.

Comment: The Content might be seen as a part of ZipFile because each ZipFile has a Content, so I give it to the constructor. But my question is more about the pros and the cons of each solution.

Answer (score 2):

The generalizations for the two cases is different:

The first case generalizes to `ZipFile` knowing the concrete class of its contents, and returning some implementation of an interface.

The second case generalizes to `ZipFile` knowing an interface for its contents, and receiving a concrete class (to initialize later??).

Stated in another way, the first case couples `ZipFile` and whatever the concrete content class is. The second couples the client of `ZipFile` and the concrete content class.

Given that it is quite likely that `ZipFile` goes with a specific concrete class for its contents, the first generalization is probably the more natural one.